# The face recognition package not have package.xml file

Tags: groovy, ros

I got face recognition tutorial on ros wiki page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition

and the SVN link for the face recognition package:

http://www.github.com/procrob/procrob_functional/tree/master/face_recognition

I started working by creating workspace for catkin and completed basic tutorials. Added gscam package in workspace, build and able to publish stream using web-cam. After that tried to use face recognition package in catkin workspace. But the package was for rosbuild. How can I use this package with the catkin?

How I can build and run this package using the build system - catkin?

Thank You.

Comment: @tim_yates: just curious, why did you remove the groovy tag from this question?

Comment: @Mels probably because the poster meant Groovy as in the version of ROS (Groovy Galapagos), not the language the tag is for

Comment: @Mels what Humungus said ;-)

Comment: Ah, ok. Not familiar with either one, hence my confusion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to convert the package from [robuild to catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild).

It may seem a bit daunting at first glance.

Have look at the `ros_comm` package to get an example of `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`